# Can I call a function inside mysql query?

Tags: c++, mysql

can I call a function inside an MySQL Query? To ask more elaborately consider I have a function which returns the account_id of the customer

```
int return_account_id(){

    return (account_id);

}
```

Now can I call this function inside my query ? Is it possible ?

```
`resultset = statement->executeQuery("SELECT `account_id`, `acc_name` FROM `account` WHERE `account_id` = "return_account_id()" ");
```

Comment: Just avoid globals/singleton and pass the information.

Comment: to be exact, it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this:

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream query;
query << "SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_id = " << return_account_id() << ";";
resultset = statement->executeQuery(query.str());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Remember, your C++ code is *application* code.  The SQL statement is server code, potentially running on a different machine.

But, the answer is not "No".  You can add user defined functions that MySQL knows about.  If you need to do this, the place to start is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html).